# "Extract String Resource" option not showing up despite being enabled in Android 3.5.1

Tags: string, extract

I am an Android newbie building my first app so could really use your guidance. When I click on a hard coded string in activity_main.xml and press Alt + Enter, the context menu I get does not show an "Extract String Resource" option. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WujQH.jpg)

I read in another post to check if it was disabled by pressing ctrl + shift + enter and it says that it is enabled. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TlUQ.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)